# Read and register EventStream API in python

Tags: python, api, python-requests, server-sent-events

I did this code to connect to an API and read the data. (I removed the Cookie and URL)

```
import requests
import urllib3
import json
import sseclient
import pprint

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += ':HIGH:!DH:!aNULL'

parameter = {
    "Cookie" : ""
}


response2 = requests.get("", headers=parameter, verify=False, stream=True)
print(response2.status_code)
for a in response2.iter_lines(chunk_size=1024, decode_unicode=True):
    print(a)
```

It works but the data are not very clean. Example :

```
data: {"id":"1660609778692","timestamp":1660636693,"heure":35893,"sens":1,"action":"A"}

event: heartbeat
data: 

data: {"id":"1660604578692","timestamp":1660636665,"heure":35864,"sens":2,"action":"A"}
```

Can you tell me how to clean the data ? maybe have a json format.
Is there a good way to register the data in a file ?

If you have advice to improve the code, it would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by cleaning the data? We would need to see the data you need to have "cleaned" and what you expect of the output.

Comment: I would like to have something like that :
`
{"type":"data","id":"1660609778692","timestamp":1660636693,"heure":35893,"sens":1,"action":"A"}

{"type":"heartbeat"}

{"type":"data","id":"1660604578692","timestamp":1660636665,"heure":35864,"sens":2,"action":"A"}
`
And register it in a file